# Drupal users getting blocked automatically

Tags: users, 7

I am experiencing a strange problem with my drupal website. On it, there are a good number of registered users. Sometime the users login, but not very frequently. Suddenly I figured out that some of the users (who are relatively old) are getting blocked. I check with blocked users, they said they did nothing. I do not have any idea how they got blocked.

Ok, then I unblock them manually and now they are active. Next day, I find them blocked again. So, now I need to unblock a bunch of users manually which is not the optimal way to deal with the users.

Anyidea? Anybody?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Do you happen to have the [Inactive User](https://www.drupal.org/project/inactive_user) module installed? This module can be used to block users who are inactive for some time. Otherwise, are you sure that the users are not trying to log in with the wrong password (5 times), which would also block them. It could be possible that someone else is trying to log in with these user accounts and is getting them blocked (I suppose it would be up to you to decide how likely this is based on whether or not your website is fairly high or low profile).